# How to know number of child allotted to individual p1?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-analysis, recursive-query

In the below data(df2), I need to know how many(count) children every p1 have?
for example: In [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO9GD.png) a single p1 is showing.
I need a data table for this picture in the following form.

```
p1_id | no. of p1|no. of p2| no. of p3 |
374971| 1        |3        | 4         |
....  |.....     |......   |.....      |
```

given that: there is no certain hierarchy. like, may be possible that p1 have another p1 under him or p3 under him. And there may be n number of branches and node possible.

Df2

```
   id   title   parent_id
0   11  p1          11
1   12  p1          11
2   13  p2          12
3   14  p2          12
4   15  p2          13
5   16  p2          13
6   17  p3          13
```

This df2 problem should give output like

```
p1_id | no. of p1|no. of p2| no. of p3 |
11    | 1        |4        | 1         |
12    | 0        |2        | 0         |
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,
You just want to count how many p1, p2, p3, etc are there per parent_id.
In this case, you can do .groupby using a list of two columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'c_id':[374971,363401,373600,363401],
     'title':['p1','p2','p1','p3'],
     'parent_id':[443547,360652,256963,360652]
    })

df.groupby(['parent_id','title']).count()
```

Will give a result which is similar to what you wanted, but not quite in the same format:

```
parent_id   title   c_id    
256963      p1      1
360652      p2      1
            p3      1
443547      p1      1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but this will show only immediate child not the grandchilds. please refer image